# Asp.net/SQL - Retrieving data from multiple tables using foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and SQL, and I'm trying to build a Web Forms project that will basically display data using grids.

I'm using Entity Framework along with a Data Transfer Object and a Data Access Layer for displaying/editing data.

My issue is that I'm not sure what is the best way of retrieving data using foreign keys.

Example:

**Table 1 - Products**

```
|(PK) Product ID | Product Name | Country ID(FK)
```

**Table 2 - Countries**

```
|(PK) Country ID | Country Name|
```

**Final Result Should be:**

```
Product ID | Product Name | Country Name|
```

What's the best way to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make LINQ query from this one. Better, you create one separate class and retrieve only data which you want.

SQL Query :

```
SELECT P.ProductID, P.ProductName, C.COuntryName FROM Products P
INNER JOIN ON Countries C ON C.CountryID = P.CountryID
```

Execute Query using EF :

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<ProductDTO>(query).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is use a projection to do that.
Your code will be similar to the code below:

```
context.Products.Select(x=>new ProductDto
{
   ProductId=x.ProductId,
   ProductName=x.Name,
   CountryName=x.Country.Name
});
```

Using projections you will ensure that is retrieving only the necessary data from DB.

Hope this helps!